# How to pass selected value from AutoComplete to another component in Reactjs

Tags: javascript, reactjs, graphql, material-ui, react-apollo

I have one parent component `Questions` and two child components: `Question1` and `Question2`. 
`Question1` and `Question2` both return an `AutoComplete component` (from `material-ui`). The options of `Question2` should be based on whatever is selected in `Question1` (`graphql` request using the selected value as input). I read a lot on how to pass a value between sibling components but I can't find an obvious way to do it for this case. I just need some guidance on how to approach this.

This is the structure of my code:

```
export const Questions = ({ questionLabel }: QuestionsProps) => {
  return (<div>
    <Question1 />
    <Question2 />
  </div>
  )
    //-
    export const Question1 = () => {
    const [open, setOpen] = React.useState(false);
    const [options, setOptions] = React.useState([]);
    return (
      <Autocomplete
        open={open}
        onOpen={() => {
          setOpen(true);
        }}
        onClose={() => {
          setOpen(false);
        }}
        options={options}
        loading={loading}
        autoHighlight
        onChange={
          (event, value) => {
            console.log(value)
          }
        }
            //...
            )


      //-

            export const Question2 = () => {
      const [open, setOpen] = React.useState(false);
      const [options, setOptions] = React.useState([]);
      const { loading, data } = useQuery(query2, {
        variables: { selectedFromQuestion1: *** need the value here *** }});

    useEffect(() => {
      if (!open) {
        setOptions([]);
      } else {
        if (data) {
          setOptions(data.info.data);
        }
      }
    }, [open]);

  }
  return (
    <Autocomplete
      open={open}
      onOpen={() => {
        setOpen(true);
      }}
      onClose={() => {
        setOpen(false);
      }}
      options={options}
      loading={loading}
      autoHighlight
      onChange={
        (event, value) => {
          console.log(value)
        }
      }
            //...
            )

    -
```

Comment: Add local state and a `handleChange` function to update that state to the `Questions` parent. Pass down that function as `onChange={handleChange}` to `Question1`, which will then use `onChange={props.onChange}`. That will update the state in your parent and you can now pass down the selected value(s) to `Questions2`

Comment: @hotpink I'm not sure I follow, the value is being updated in `Question1` so what will be implemented inside `handleChange` in `Questions`? Thanks

Comment: the callback for `onChange` can store the selected value to your component state. Currently you just log it to the console. Instead of putting that callback inside `Question1`, you pass it down as a prop. Same function, same functionality, you simply define it elsewhere.

Comment: https://reactjs.org/docs/lifting-state-up.html